# Apache HTTP Server - Route Request by SOAP Body Element

Tags: apache, soap

For example:

For every SAOP request with method X with a SOAP body

```
<soap:Body>
   <GetTutorialInfo>
        <TutorialName>Web Services</TutorialName> 
        <TutorialDescription>All about web services</TutorialDescription>
        <Option>server1</Option>
   </GetTutorialInfo>
</soap:Body>
```

I would like Apache to route the request to a certain virtual host if Option element is "server1" and do not route otherwise.

Can this be done with configuration or must I create a custom module?

Comment: Why you want to create `proxy` rules `request-boby` rather then `url` pattern, I think its better if you minimize the complications on `web-server`. You should be keeping the complication in `application`, then `web-server`.

Comment: Yeah I would really like that. But what is being requested is to route a request based only on one parameter in the request body.

Comment: if you don't have constrained of using `Apache` web server only, then I could suggest a solution on other `web-server`, let me know.